# Distribute 20 identical candy among five children: three toddlers and two first graders, if the first graders have to get at least two each?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many ways can you distribute 20 identical candy among five children:
> three toddlers and two first graders, if the first graders have to get at least
> two each?

Comment: Vandalism, flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: I have rolled back the question. Please do not obscure this question; others may benefit from it, and the answers make no sense without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first graders have to get at least two each, there are $20-4 = 16$ pieces of candy that are free to distribute. So now we want to know how many ways you can distribute $16$ piecies of candy among five children with no further constraints. Do you know the method of "stars and bars"?

Comment: If this is the same as the sticks and stones method, then yes

Comment: However, I don't think we can just subtract 4, as the questions says that the first graders have to get ATLEAST two ... i.e. they can get 2 or more. So how would we take that into account?

Comment: @Sarah Like he said, determine the number of ways to distribute the remaining 16 pieces among 5 children.  That 5 includes the first graders.  Subtracting the 4 is for giving them 2 each up front, but they're still eligible to receive more candy.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Then is 5 factorial + 4 the answer?

Comment: @Sarah I believe you're way too low.  I assume with the sticks and stones method you're referring to, you have a row of stones which each represent one candy to be distributed and a few sticks as dividers separating each child's take from one another.  How many ways are there to choose the locations of the sticks?

Comment: That's the method I tried to use, but am not sure how to use it in this question.

Comment: To use "sticks and stones" here, we start with 16 stones, which are pieces of candy. Then we add 4 more objects, these are the sticks that separate the candy into 5 piles. We thus have 20 total objects. The task now is to choose $4$ of these objects to be the sticks, which automatically induces a division of the remaining 16 objects into five piles, corresponding to a distribution of candy. This gives $20 \choose 4$ possibilities.

Comment: So is the final answer 20 choose 4 then?

Comment: That is correct.